# Adding components after the main root ReactJs (adding another block)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I am a newbie in reactjs
I deployed a landing page (found on github) which is working fine and I customized the page a bit
result here >
https://photographe-paris.virtueltime.com/

then I wanted to add another block at the end of the page
here is the code I did (jsx)
https://photographe-paris.virtueltime.com/jsx.html (that I want to add at the end of the page in reactjs)

I tried adding the code of the second page to the first page but it is not working

the code of the second page is here
`enter code here`https://codepen.io/Gerald-Mardirossian/pen/XWePKrB`enter code here`
in JS is the content from https://photographe-paris.virtueltime.com/jsx.js

any idea why ?

thank you for your help

Comment: add your code part also here, what you tried

Comment: this link https://photographe-paris.virtueltime.com/ contains currently both the code from the start + the code added (which you can see on https://photographe-paris.virtueltime.com/jsx.html )

code is added after <div id="root"></div>

Comment: if you want the component outside the root div you have to create a empty div in the index.html file in the public dir let's say you add `<div id='comp'></div>`. then render your component `ReactDOM.render(<Component />, document.getElementById("comp"))`

Comment: after 
<div id="root"></div>

I have added

 <div id="content3"></div>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="content2"></div>

and also a .Js (jsx) which is supposed to generate the block (working on https://photographe-paris.virtueltime.com/jsx.html )

but not on https://photographe-paris.virtueltime.com/

is there a compatibility issue maybe ?

Comment: Is the block that you want to add a JSX function?

Comment: I am trying to add the whole content of https://photographe-paris.virtueltime.com/jsx.html (you can view the all source code on your browser)
main code is here https://photographe-paris.virtueltime.com/jsx.js
is that jsx ? (I am newbie / thanks)

Comment: I have maybe on another problem also, when cloudflare is ON, the page https://photographe-paris.virtueltime.com/jsx.html  does not work....weird...I have just put back the dev mode of cloudflare on therefore )

Comment: Please include the code that you'd want to add, in your question, so that we can help you in adding. The code in browser is minfied and hard to read.

Comment: Is your main page(landing page) in React?

Comment: yes main page is in reactJS  ////
I have added a codepen > https://codepen.io/Gerald-Mardirossian/pen/XWePKrB for the second page

Answer (score 0):

You can import the second page inside the first page and render it in the first-page return method.
For example, This is my first-page Firstpage.jsx

```
import './App.css';
import React from 'react';
import Secondpage from './Secondpage';
class Firstpage extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
  super(props);
    this.state = {    
    }   
   
  }


render() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>Hiii, This is my first page</div>
      <Secondpage></Secondpage>
    </div>
  );
  }
}
export default Firstpage;
```

And below is my second-page component, which I imported into my first page.
Secondpage.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
class Secondpage extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
  super(props);
    this.state = {
    }   
  }


render() {
  return (
    <div >
    This is my second page
    </div>
  );
  }
}
export default Secondpage;
```

Comment: thank you for you reply 
my firstpage > is not in jsx (just reactjs) / I don't know if it changes anything... or not

////// As a newbie, your solution looks more complicated to the way I was trying to add the code manually after <div id="root"></div> ...but, is the way I was trying to do just not possible ?

thanks

Comment: I have maybe on another problem also, when cloudflare is ON, the page https://photographe-paris.virtueltime.com/jsx.html in jsx does not work....weird...

Answer (score 0):

JSX is nothing but JavaScript extended, which means using HTML in JavaScript files.
Component functions are JSX in nature because they return HTML elements in their return function, a regular reactJS file would be something that doesn't return HTML elements, but make use of react-specific function like hooks. So, to make things clear, if a reactJS file returns HTML, it is JSX in nature.
Coming to adding the content to the main page, you could make use of something called [portals](https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html). You can use portals to inject content adjacent to root elements (div with id content,content2 etc.) in your case.

So, in your jsx.js, remove `React.render` and change `var` to `const` (not mandatory) and export the components:
`jsx.js` after changes:

```
export const MyComponent3 = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    const name = (
      <div className="greeting3">
        <center>
          <h2>DÃ©couvrez notre portfolio (en cours de construction)</h2>
        </center>

        <div className="containphotos">
          <a
            href="https://photographe-paris.virtueltime.com/portfolio/"
            title="portfolio"
          >
            <div id="firstimage"></div>
          </a>
          <a
            href="https://photographe-paris.virtueltime.com/portfolio/"
            title="portfolio"
          >
            <div id="secondimage"></div>
          </a>
          <a
            href="https://photographe-paris.virtueltime.com/portfolio/"
            title="portfolio"
          >
            <div id="thirdimage"></div>
          </a>
          <a
            href="https://photographe-paris.virtueltime.com/portfolio/"
            title="portfolio"
          >
            <div id="fourthimage"></div>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    );

    return <div> {name}</div>;
  },
});

export const MyComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    const name = (
      <div className="greeting">
        <div id="ff-compose"></div>
      </div>
    );

    return <div> {name}</div>;
  },
});

export const MyComponent2 = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    const name2 = (
      <div className="greeting2">
        <a
          href="https://www.virtueltime.com/visite-virtuelle/mentions-legales/"
          title="Mentions lÃ©gales"
          target="_blank"
        >
          Mentions lÃ©gales
        </a>{" "}
        -{" "}
        <a
          href="https://www.virtueltime.com/plan-site-agence-digitale-paris/"
          title="Plan du site web"
          target="_blank"
        >
          Plan du site web
        </a>{" "}
        -{" "}
        <a
          href="https://www.virtueltime.com/visite-virtuelle/blog-news/"
          target="_blank"
          title="Blog Digital"
        >
          Blog
        </a>{" "}
        -{" "}
        <a
          href="https://recrutement.virtueltime.com/#home"
          target="_blank"
          title="Recrutement"
        >
          Recrutement
        </a>{" "}
        -{" "}
        <a
          href="https://intranet.virtueltime.com/"
          title="Solution Intranet"
          target="_blank"
        >
          Solution Intranet
        </a>{" "}
        -{" "}
        <a
          href="https://www.virtueltime.com/nos-partenaires/"
          title="Partenaires"
          target="_blank"
        >
          Partenaires
        </a>{" "}
        -{" "}
        <a
          href="https://www.virtueltime.com/visite-virtuelle/nos-references/"
          title="Nos rÃ©fÃ©rences"
        >
          Nos rÃ©fÃ©rences
        </a>{" "}
        -{" "}
        <a
          href="https://www.virtueltime.com/visite-virtuelle/services-digitaux/"
          target="_blank"
          title="Nos services digitaux"
        >
          Nos services digitaux
        </a>{" "}
        -{" "}
        <a
          href="https://www.virtueltime.com/visite-virtuelle/exemples-visites-virtuelles/"
          title="Visites virtuelles et google street views"
          target="_blank"
        >
          {" "}
          Visites virtuelles & street views
        </a>{" "}
        -{" "}
        <a
          href="https://www.virtueltime.com/visite-virtuelle/devis-visite-virtuelle-photo/"
          title="Contact Demande Devis photo Digital"
          target="_blank"
        >
          Contact
        </a>{" "}
        -{" "}
        <a
          href="mailto:contact@virtueltime.com?subject=Devis photo"
          title="nous contacter par email"
        >
          ðŸ“§
        </a>{" "}
        -{" "}
        <a href="tel:0781263726" title="Nous appeler">
          âœ†
        </a>
      </div>
    );

    return <div> {name2}</div>;
  },
});
```

Then in your main component file, import these components and render them by creating a portal.
In your `App.js` or `App.jsx` or main component file:

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {MyComponent,MyComponent2,MyComponent3} from 'path/to/jsx.js_file'

export default function App(){

return(
.
.
.
{ReactDOM.createPortal(<MyComponent/>,document.getElementById('content')}
{ReactDOM.createPortal(<MyComponent2/>,document.getElementById('content2')}
{ReactDOM.createPortal(<MyComponent3/>,document.getElementById('content3')}
)
}
```

Make sure that you've added `div`s with id `content`, `content2` and `content3` in your `index.html`.

Comment: by "In your App.js or App.jsx or main component file:" / do you mean I have to generate a new build ? I cannot modify directly the files on my "build" folder ?
//// In the build folder, I do have a "    "main.js": "/static/js/main.82a3af84.js", but I can't understand much of it...

Comment: Yes, you should update your App.js/App.jsx by adding the necessary code and rebuilding your project, the build folder is a minified bundle and is Pure JS, since the code that needs to be added is react specific, you should first add it and then rebuild the build folder.

Answer (score 0):

you have to add in your index.html

> const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));

> const element = add your component; root.render(element);